# heroku dependencies fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm trying for the first time to deploy an app to heroku and I'm getting the following error.  The list of gems on heroku includes this version of the bson gem, and my gemfile includes `source 'http://rubygems.org'` at the top.  Can anyone suggest why the gem is not being found?

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
       Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done
-----> Configure Rails 3 to disable x-sendfile
       Installing rails3_disable_x_sendfile... done
-----> Configure Rails to log to stdout
       Installing rails_log_stdout... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
       Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
       Using --without development:test
       Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
       Could not find bson-1.4.1 in any of the sources
       FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the 1.4.1 version of BSON for Ruby was yanked - nothing to do with Heroku.

http://rubygems.org/gems/bson/versions

Comment: thanks - that answers this question -but raises another which I'll ask separately

Comment: @chrispanda: rejected your edit because you should add it as an other answer

Answer (score 1):

John's answer was the clue -

```
    gem 'mongoid', '= 2.3.0'
    gem 'bson', '= 1.4.0'
    gem 'bson_ext', '= 1.4.0'
```

works for me

Comment: i'm having same exact problem, but I'm using mongoid 2.2.4. I sat bson & bson_ext 1.3.1 with no luck. Every time I push to Heroku I get the same error. Any idea? I removed all gems in vendor/cache, removed Gemfile.lock just to be sure. Also removed gems under the .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2